# Почему такой огромный скачок между датами Date?

Tags: java

Было задание построить график дат, но на графике появились прыжки большие, оказалось проблема в переходе между датами в новый год. В связи с чем назрел вопрос, почему дата так сильно меняется, если разница в 2 секунды?

```
        String s = "31.12.2009 23:59:59";
        String s1 = "01.01.2010 00:00:01";
        Long date = null, date1=null;
        SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        try {
            date = dt.parse(s).getTime();
            date1 = dt.parse(s1).getTime();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Вывод:

```
Result
1233439199000
1262296801000

Difference in 28857602000
```

Comment: mm - это месяцы или минуты?

Comment: @andreymal сначала mm - месяцы, а потом минуты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> сначала mm - месяцы, а потом минуты

Нет уж. Что-нибудь одно.

```
SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Спасибо огромное, уже поправил!